# Using WebAPI 2.2 inside of an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I am using WebAPI 2.2, with Attribute Routing, inside of an existing MVC 5 project. I intend to migrate the entire website over to WebAPI, but it will take some time. I got everything working, but I am concerned I may be doing something wrong.

[This SO post seems to suggest I should be calling GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) in the Global.asax.cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882260/web-api-attribute-routes-in-mvc-5-exception-the-object-has-not-yet-been-initial).

If I simply remove the HttpConfiguration argument typically provided in `WebApiConfig.Register()`, and simply call `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes())` within the `WebApiConfig.Register()` method - the WebAPI endpoints respond with the desired results.

So this is what I end up with:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}


class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there are simply two ways to fix the configuration issue that comes up when WebAPI 2.2 is added to an existing project. I was doing BOTH fixes which became clear to me when I read the code.

The following:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}


class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
    }
}
```

Is virtually the same as doing the following:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //WebApiConfig.Register();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}

class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

It seems I was simply experiencing a mental lapse :)

It should have been obvious that `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes())` is basically doing the same thing as `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)`.

It logically follows that these should produce the same result. Here is the Microsoft code for GlobalConfiguration in the System.Web.Http namespace:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a global <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration"/> for ASP.NET applications.
/// </summary>
public static class GlobalConfiguration
{
    private static Lazy<HttpConfiguration> _configuration = CreateConfiguration();

    ///... code excluded for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the global <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static HttpConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get { return _configuration.Value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs configuration for <see cref="GlobalConfiguration.Configuration"/> and ensures that it is
    /// initialized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configurationCallback">The callback that will perform the configuration.</param>
    public static void Configure(Action<HttpConfiguration> configurationCallback)
    {
        if (configurationCallback == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("configurationCallback");
        }

        configurationCallback.Invoke(Configuration);
        Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static Lazy<HttpConfiguration> CreateConfiguration()
    {
        return new Lazy<HttpConfiguration>(() =>
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(new HostedHttpRouteCollection(RouteTable.Routes));
            ServicesContainer services = config.Services;
            Contract.Assert(services != null);
            services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new WebHostAssembliesResolver());
            services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver());
            services.Replace(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new WebHostBufferPolicySelector());
            services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
                new WebHostExceptionHandler(services.GetExceptionHandler()));
            return config;
        });
    }

    ///... code excluded for brevity
}
```